# Merge [top-gun-2] and [top-gun-maverick]?

Tags: support

Can the tags [top-gun-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-gun-2) and [top-gun-maverick](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-gun-maverick) be merged? Or maybe delete [top-gun-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-gun-2) and retag the question (s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have removed [top-gun-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-gun-2) tag from a question. Now this tag will be removed from the system automatically if not used.